# How to Preserve Whitespace (Regex)

Tags: python, regex, join, whitespace

I'm pretty new programming and I'm trying to use regex to print strings containing **only** letters. But I'm having one problem. I also want to preserve any whitespace. So this is what I have:

`value = 'h&(()^%el!!l000o w@0or!ld'`

`import re`

`value = ''.join(re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+',value))`

`print value`

`helloworld`

The output that I want is: **hello world**. I think part of the problem is that I'm using .join. How can I preserve the whitespace but also make sure that only letters are printing?

Comment: Use `' '.join(...)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match whitespace in your regex, as well as matching letters. You can do this by adding `\s` to your regex as follows:

```
import re

value = 'h&(()^%el!!l000o w@0or!ld'
value = ''.join(re.findall('[a-zA-Z\s]+',value))
print value
```

**Output**

```
hello world
```

Comment: Good stuff - glad to have helped